# cannot create array from datamapper orm query to populate form_dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper

Hi there here is my datamapper model

```
function getall()
    {
        $states = new Usstate();
        $states->get();
        $usstates_array = array();
        foreach ($states as $state) 
        {
           $usstates_array[$state->abbreviation] = $state->state;
        } 
         return $usstates_array;
    }
```

And here is my Controller

```
function getall()
    {
        $s = new Usstate();
        $data['states'] = $s->getall();
        $this->parser->parse('register', $data);
    }
```

I get an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when i pass $states into the form_dropdown helper function in my view.

so i did a print_r on states, and it was completely empty.

Please help

**Update:**

Ok i finally got it working, i am not to sure about the explanation, but this is what i did.

my datamapper model

```
function getall()
    {
        $states = new Usstate();
        $statecollection = $states->get();
        $usstates_array = array();
        foreach ($statecollection as $state) 
        {
           $usstates_array[$state->abbreviation] = $state->state;
        } 
         return $usstates_array;
    }
```

and also make sure you have more than one row in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datamapper implements IteratorAggregate, which allows you to iterate over the object like you would an array. Both your examples are valid.

As for the original question, I don't see any reason why that would not work, although I would prefer to work with $this instead of create a new object, as you are already in a Usstate object.

Even if the get() doesn't produce any results, you should be able to use the object in a foreach(), it would be like iterating over an empty array.

Have you var_dump()'d the $states variable to see what it contains before the foreach?

Comment: Wow i did not realize who just answered my question. Wow thank you so much for awesome work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
foreach($states->get() as $state)
```

Instead of:

```
foreach($states as $state)
```

Don't forget that `$states` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

this is the function on your model.. to return an array with the id

```
    public function getall() {
            // id and the colum you want to show in your form_dropdown
            $this->select('id, name')->get(); 

            $ids = array();
            $names = array();

            foreach ($this as $rows) {
                $ids[] = $rows->id;
                $names[] = $rows->name;
            }        

            return array_combine($ids, $names);
        }
```

... hope you like it :D

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to mention: the Array extension contains a method that allows you to convert the result of a query into a single key=>value array, for this specific use.